# highlighting a selected div ng-repeat for mvc

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, model-view-controller

I have a repeater div getting information from a json file. When I select a div, it gets the information from the json file and populates the div below it. As much as I try, I can't seem to get the correct selected div to highlight. No matter what I do, it highlights the first record and no others. I also can't unselect it.

My code is as follows:

```
.highlight {
            background-color: cyan;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

    <div ng-controller=ItemsController >
        <div style="overflow-y:scroll; height: 300px; max-height: 600px; margin: 16px;">
            <label class="labelQuestion" style="font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;" id="lblWN" for="lblWorkplaceName"><b>Workplace / Function </b></label>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row" id="pap" ng-click="select(item)" ng-repeat="item in itemDetails" @*ng-repeat="papitem in pap"*@>
                    <div class="papdiv" style="width: 100%">
                        <div style="width: 20%; float: left;"><label class="labelQuestion" style="font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;" id="lblWN" for="lblWorkplaceName"><b>Workplace Name: </b></label></div>
                        <div style="width: 80%; float: right;">
                            <label class="labelQuestion" style="font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;" id="lblWorkplaceName">{{item.WorkplaceName}}</label>
                        </div>
                        <div style="width: 80%; float: right; color:black;">
                            <hr class="style-one">
                        </div>

                        <div style="width: 20%; float: left;"><label class="labelQuestion" style="font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; padding-top:41px;" id="lblWN" for="lblFunctionName"><b>Function Name: </b></label></div>
                        <div style="width: 80%; float: right;">
                            <label class="labelQuestion" style="font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;" id="lblWorkplaceName">{{item.FunctionName}} > {{item.BusinessUnit}} > {{item.ValueStream}} > {{item.WorkStream}} > {{item.Process}}</label>

                            <span class="tooltiptext">{{item.FunctionName}} > {{item.BusinessUnit}} > {{item.ValueStream}} > {{item.WorkStream}} > {{item.Process}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
```

JS file:

```
PapWidget.factory('itemsFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
var itemsFactory = {
    itemDetails: function () {
        return $http(
            {
                url: "mockItems.json",
                method: "GET",
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
    }
};
return itemsFactory;

}]);

PapWidget.controller('ItemsController', ['$scope', 'itemsFactory', '$log', '$q', '$http', '$filter',
 function ($scope, itemsFactory, $log, $q, $http, $filter) {

    var promise = itemsFactory.itemDetails();

    promise.then(function (data) {
        $scope.itemDetails = data;
        console.log(data);
    });

    var classHighlight = 'highlight';
    var $thumbs = $('.row').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $thumbs.removeClass(classHighlight);
        $(this).addClass(classHighlight);
    });

    $scope.select = function (item)
    {
        $scope.selected = item;
        alert("Selected: " + $scope.selected);
    }
    $scope.selected = {};
```

I want to be able to highlight the div on click of it. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled doing this the other day and came up with a hack. I use ng-repeat track by $index and ng-click="addClass($index)". Which appends the object with a {selected: true}. Then I have an ng-class that looks to see if that value is true and adds the class other wise, there is no class.

So in my .html file looked something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
   <div ng-click="addClass($index)" 
      ng-class="{selected:(items[$index].selected)?true:false}">
        {{item.name}}
   </div>
</div>
```

And in my controller.js looked something like this:

```
$scope.addClass = function(idx){
    //First I made all selected to false;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.unAssignedUnits.length; i++) {
       $scope.items[i].selected = false;
    }
    //Then i made the item that was clicked set to true;
    $scope.items[idx].selected = true;
}
```

Then my styles.scss looked something like this:

```
selected{
    color: red;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! That helped a great deal! Got the background color to change and work perfectly.